# how to fix Unterminated string constant

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am getting this error: `Unterminated string constant` on the Console window. I'm retrieving data from the Database, and all are in String Format. But For one Field, I am getting the error `Unterminated string constant`. It seems that string is not in correct format. But I can see in the Database its correct: "**Municipality Sample s**" I want to retrieve this string, but it's not working.

Does somebody know what I'm doing wrong here?

```
WorkflowMasterReference.GASubTypeCode = '<% = LinkToBOs.WorkflowMasterReference.GASubTypeCode%>';
WorkflowMasterReference.GASubTypeDesc = '<%=LinkToBOs.WorkflowMasterReference.GASubTypeDesc%>';
```

While debugging I can see that the data is binded with like this It's clearing seen string is not in correct format but this type of data is appearing

[image]

Comment: You cannot have multiline strings in JavaScript. Either make it a single line (seems like it should be anyway), or change it to a template string by using `\`` instead of quotes.

Comment: @VLAZ can you Suggest me sample code for that Please ?

Comment: No, because I don't know what produces this invalid code. I just know how to fix it. You have to find why it's produced wrong in the first place.

Comment: After fetching Record can we modify this multi String to single string ?